# Load theme files in Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: command-line, gnome, 15.04, themes, gnome-terminal

It seems that loading the Gnome Terminal theme files is not working anymore in Ubuntu 15.04:

```
gconftool-2 --load terminal-flat-theme.xml
```

This does *not* change my current theme.

The theme file looks like [this](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/terminal-flat-theme/blob/ddb5c065431450e7994823890a10c32a0c65c33c/terminal-flat-theme.xml).

How can I load this XML file as theme?

Comment: Have you tried using the Gnome Tweak Tool GUI to configure this?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda I'm  not sure how would that work. This is a terminal theme not a Gtk theme.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda 15.04–it may be related to some recent changes, because this did work in the past.

Comment: As you can see with `dconf-editor`, it has changed everything.

Comment: @A.B. What do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem in the past. I overcame it, by generating a file that is readable by the new version (3.14.2). To do this, you can visit a site called terminal.sexy, upload your theme there, and convert it to a gnome-terminal compatible shell script. It worked for me, because I had been using the tomorrow theme by base16.

**The one line install method :**

run the command `wget -O - http://git.io/vZijG | bash` and skip to step 5.

**Steps to install the theme manually:**

1. save the context of the file in a shell file (for example, theme.sh).
2. then run the script by running the command `sh filename.sh`or if you make the script executable by running `chmod +x filename.sh`, then you can simply run the script by running the command `./filename.sh`.
3. Next, you can go to **terminal -> change profile.**
4. You will see a list of profiles there, where, if you run the script I have given above, will be called `terminal.flat.theme`.
5. Next, you can go to **terminal -> preferences -> profiles**, and select Profile used when launching the terminal as the new profile we just created (in this case, it will be named `terminal.flat.theme`.
6. **Restart**, and **Voila**, your new theme will appear.

The content of the theme file can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/anmoljagetia/263d14f30db7b703ad3e).

Comment: How to do this? Could you add please some screenshots or step-by-step instructions? Sounds good.

Comment: I can generate a script for your colors, but I am afraid I am not very proficient with including other settings and shortcuts in it. Also, I will add a few screenshots, to improve the overall quality of the answer.

Comment: Sure, if you generate a script that could be also nice. I'm happy to award you the bounty, but I need the solution. I exported the theme and run the script they gave me but still it doesn't change anything in my Gnome Terminal (and I did select *Gnome Terminal* in the export dialogs).

Comment: The site is designed with xterm and mac in mind, but there is a workaround for making it work on Gnome-Terminal. I will modify the answer to include all the steps.

Comment: Please find the script [here](https://gist.github.com/anmoljagetia/263d14f30db7b703ad3e#file-terminalflattheme-sh).

There is also a one-liner install by running the following command :
wget -O xt http://git.io/vZijG && chmod +x xt && ./xt && rm xt

Comment: Man, you're great! :)