# How can I apply the Dracula terminal theme?

Tags: command-line, themes

I just downloaded [Dracula terminal theme](https://draculatheme.com/terminal/) and I cannot apply it. How does one apply a theme to terminal on Ubuntu?

Comment: The *theme* you got is for the iOS terminal. You could try to mimic it, though, going to *Terminal>Preferences>Profiles>Edit* and choose the colors manually to look like the Dracula one.

Answer (score 5):

The theme you got is for the iOS terminal.

You could try to mimic it, though, going to **Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Edit** and choose the colors manually to look like the Dracula one.

---

Or you can use this website [Terminal.sexy:](http://terminal.sexy/)

[image]

To help you select the colors, and either download an import or manually set your colour palette.

More about it and how: [Load theme files in Gnome Terminal on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668227/load-theme-files-in-gnome-terminal-on-ubuntu-15-04?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but currently there is a theme for GNOME Terminal (currently used by Ubuntu): https://draculatheme.com/gnome-terminal